# Burning chometz with an electric fire?

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven

Assuming we treat electric appliances that create glowing red metal as fire in regard to shabbos, is anyone aware of any teshuva that discuss using it for burning chometz (aside from the Rashash Shabbos 66b that would be against which Minchas Yitzchok (2:53) rejects - first saw in dirshu). Not looking for reyd on tashbisu.

Comment: Are you sure we treat it as fire for Shabbos? I think it is just treated as part of the melacha of bishul, more like the food than the fire.

Comment: Once the electric elements sets the *chametz* on fire, it would burn? *Le'mai naphkah minah* how you set start the fire?

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Is your main question regarding burning chometz using glowing-red metal (regardless of how it was heated)? or is it regarding burning chometz using electricity (regardless of whether metal gets heated up)? These are two separate topics, and Rav Sh. Z. Auerbach discusses both points separately regarding Hilchos Shabbos.